# Parsing JSON array with unknown field names?

Tags: php, json, parsing

So I have this json:

```
{
  "success": true,
  "rgInventory": {
    "4580331488": {
      "id": "4580331488",
      "classid": "520025252",
      "instanceid": "0",
      "amount": "1",
      "pos": 1
    },
    "4566197481": {
      "id": "4566197481",
      "classid": "1439482117",
      "instanceid": "188530139",
      "amount": "1",
      "pos": 2
    },
    "4566196610": {
      "id": "4566196610",
      "classid": "1439484944",
      "instanceid": "188530139",
      "amount": "1",
      "pos": 3
    },
    "4566097797": {
      "id": "4566097797",
      "classid": "310776859",
      "instanceid": "302028390",
      "amount": "1",
      "    pos": 4
    },
    "4565915026": {
      "id": "4565915026",
      "classid": "310776840",
      "instanceid": "302028390",
      "amount": "1",
      "    pos": 5
    },
    "4565415060": {
      "id": "4565415060",
      "classid": "1439489161",
      "instanceid": "188530139",
      "amount": "1",
      "pos": 6
    },
    "4565413906": {
      "id": "4565413906",
      "classid": "1439484334",
      "instanceid": "188530139",
      "amount": "1",
      "pos": 7
    },
    "4559798755": {
      "id": "4559798755",
      "classid": "520025252",
      "instanceid": "0",
      "amount": "1",
      "pos": 8
    },
    "4553954652": {
      "id": "4553954652",
      "classid": "520025252",
      "instanceid": "0",
      "amount": "1",
      "pos": 9
    },
    "4553694029": {
      "id": "4553694029",
      "classid": "991959905",
      "instanceid": "0",
      "amount": "1",
      "pos": 10
    },
    "4553694015": {
      "id": "4553694015",
      "classid": "720289133",
      "instanceid": "188530170",
      "amount": "1",
      "    pos": 11
    },
    "4553694006": {
      "id": "4553694006",
      "classid": "1364486740",
      "instanceid": "188530139",
      "amount": "1",
      "pos": 12
    },
    "4553693992": {
      "id": "4553693992",
      "classid": "1309991239",
      "instanceid": "188530139",
      "amount": "1",
      "pos": 13
    },
    "4553693986": {
      "id": "4553693986",
      "classid": "310776711",
      "instanceid": "302028390",
      "amount": "1",
      "    pos": 14
    }
  }
```

I need to get it as an array and parse it. The problem is that this json is from my inventory and as I fetch other people's inventory the field are gonna change, and I can't figure out how to parse it.
So far I'm here:

```
$link='http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/'.$steamid.'/inventory/json/730/2';
$string = file_get_contents($link);
$obj = json_decode($string, true);
var_dump($obj['rgInventory']);
```

At this point I can get a result, but i don't know how to go beyond that, I mean, I need to return classid and instance id of each record, but hw can this be done in a JSON like that?

Comment: Which field are gonna change, specific? Is rgInventory going to have different keys, or are the names of classId etc gonna change?

Comment: Yes, the keys are gonna change

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a `foreach` loop

```
foreach ($obj['rgInventory'] as $key => $item) {
    echo $key; // echo the "unknown" field name
    echo $item['classid']; // echo any field value
}
```